# Error with VHDL integer signal connecting Verilog integer input

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I trying to connect VHDL module's output integer port to signal. And this signal will connect other module. (This module wrote in Verilog). But I encounter this

> ERROR :
>   VHDL integer data type not supported for actual signals in component
>   instantiation across language boundaries. Port "fifo4_frame_number" is
>   an integer VHDL signal connected to a Verilog port.

I must also say that i can generate bitstream. there is no problem.

Comment: do a type conversion to a std_logic_vector. That should work across language boundaries in all tools.

Comment: This is a Xilinx error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer in VHDL is fundamentally different to an integer in Verilog, so it is no surprise that they are not compatible. The `integer` type in VHDL is like an integer type in any other language, whereas the `integer` type in Verilog is just short hand for a vector. This

```
integer i;
```

and this

```
reg signed [31:0] i;
```

are exactly equivalent in Verilog. As others have said, you need to convert to `std_logic_vector` in VHDL.

Comment: How about any citations or references?  We've got a comment and two answer essentially providing the same assertion with no way to validate other that the OP (who didn't post any code) telling us whether it fixed his unclear problem. See  the OP's [Xiiinx forum post](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Simulation-and-Verification/Error-with-VHDL-integer-signal-connecting-Verilog-integer-input/m-p/1022827) where we find the authoritative User Guide 901 Chapter 9 cited for mixed language support specifying supported types in VHDL and Verilog Boundary Rules.

Comment: Append G in ug900 (v2017.04 linked in the Xilinx forum) shows the mapping between Systemverilog type integer and one of VHDL bit_vector std_logic_vector,
std_ulogic_vector, signed, unsigned which are all arrays with element types representing bits.

Answer (score 0):

You must convert the integer to logic_vector in your VHDL file such that the ports have the same type. Ports cannot be of integer type across both languages